# How to automatically authorise to VPN network with pritunl with username and password persisted in file on macos

Tags: macos, vpn, pritunl

Pritunl simple client is great, but it does not come with way to persist username and password for a user. Is there a way to read authorisation data form a file so login window would not have to pop up on every VPN connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On MacOS installed pritunl with configured profile for VPN network go to:

```
cd /Users/[user1]/Library/Application\ Support/pritunl/profiles/[profile_hash].ovpn
```

where profile_hash - would be alphanumeric hash like 028c16f93c....c6258
and user1 - your user obviously

Open it in your editor and find line, with **auth-user-pass** and add path to file containing you authorisation credentials

```
auth-user-pass /Users/user1/directory-to-keep-vpn-profile-data/auth.txt
```

As *Mat J* pointed out: windows users may need to escape the backslash in the path with double backslash)

auth.txt should be a plain txt file with just 2 lines:

```
username
password
```

You should restart pritunl app now in case if it was on. If everything is valid login window should not appear but app should use your authorisation data! You can use debug option in case of any problems. Usually it would be that you path to the file is wrong or auth file contains some *whitespace* like characters that affect your entry.

Keep in mind that your authorisation file is plain file. With solution above, your VPN account will be only as safe as account on machine where you put that file is.

Comment: A sidenote for windows users with same question, you need to escape the backslash in the path with double backslash.

Comment: I recommend use  `%APPDATA%/pritunl/profiles` instead, so that it is not dependent on the Windows language

Answer (score -1):

To add to the first answer. The auth.txt file might need to have its premissions changed on a mac, tho I don't know what perssimisions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31195411)